# Building apr-utils from Source on CentOS 7 — dependancy issue Ask Question

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

Im attempting to build apr-utils-1.6.1 from source on CentOS 7 (with the goal to get httpd-2.4.29) but I'm stuck with a dependancy issue:

```
# rpmbuild -tb apr-util-1.6.1.tar.bz2
error: Failed build dependencies:
    db4-devel is needed by apr-util-1.6.1-1.x86_64
```

db4-devel isn't available in yum and libdb-devel provides version 5, which doesn't meet the dependency requirement.

I've tried downloading and installing db4-devel, but that has it's own dependencies that I can't meet:

```
# rpm -iv db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64.rpm 
warning: db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    db4 = 4.7.25-22.el6 is needed by db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
    db4-cxx = 4.7.25-22.el6 is needed by db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
    libdb-4.7.so()(64bit) is needed by db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
    libdb_cxx-4.7.so()(64bit) is needed by db4-devel-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64
```

Trying to install db4 fails too because the the Berkely DB version 5 is already installed and in use on CentOS 7:

```
# rpm -iv db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64.rpm 
warning: db4-4.7.25-22.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    db4 < 5 is obsoleted by (installed) libdb-5.3.21-20.el7.x86_64
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed at this point. Do I just have to cut my losses and deploy a CentOS 6 box? It seems that CentOS 6 still has db4. I was thinking of modifying the spec file to remove the db4 requirement, but I'm not sure of the implications of that, or how to even do that properly.

Thanks.

Comment: That's just how compiling software goes.  Long unmet dependency chains are pretty common if you're trying to package something on a new platform for the first time.

Comment: To get latest http you could use this repo https://repo.codeit.guru/ Have a look at this blog https://crosp.net/blog/administration/install-latest-apache-server-centos-7/